# Python The code works but also says "index out of range"

Tags: python-3.x

I need to take every line from a file and make a dictionaries out of them
Here's my code:

```
def recnik(line):
    knjiga1 = {}
    info = line.split("|")
    knjiga1["autori"] = info[0]
    knjiga1["naslov"] = info[1]
    knjiga1["godina"] = info[2]
    knjiga1["isbn"] = info[3]
    knjiga1["zanr"] = info[4]
    knjiga1["cena"] = info[5]
    knjiga1["kolicina"] = info[6]
    knjiga1["stanje"] = info[7]

    print(knjiga1)

a = open("../data/sveKnjige.txt", "r")
for line in a:
    recnik(line)
a.close()
```

and my file looks like this:

```
Viliam Sekspir|Hamlet|1600|3214569879878|drama|6500|60|true|
Dragoslav Mihajlovic|Kad su cvetale tikve|1968|3332221115554|drama|3000|20|true|
Fjodor Dostojevski|Zlocin i kazna|1866|9788897572657|roman|4500|50|true|
Dostojevski|Ana|1995|3214569874563|triler|321|22|true|
```

This code works but also brings up this error 'list index out of range' i can't find the problem. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This code works on my machine. Are you sure that your input file is actually what you posted here?

Comment: Yes, it prints all dictionaries but also this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\OP_SII_270486\src\asd.py", line 17, in <module>
    recnik(line)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\OP_SII_270486\src\asd.py", line 5, in recnik
    knjiga1["naslov"] = info[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me too.
I've tried to provoke the error and I've had to add a last line with just a "|" to the input file character to make it fail.

Maybe you have some line with an incorrect character (in input file). Try to print the content of info in every loop.